# What is the correct UIFocusItemContainer for a SKScene? (tvOS 16)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tvos, apple-tv

I implemented a game for Apple TV where I have multiple SKSpriteNodes in a SKScene. Before tvOS 16 everything worked correctly, I could move around with the remote and focus all items in the correct way. Now, with tvOS 16, the app crashes with the following error:

```swift
Focus item RandomSKSpriteNode has a parent focus environment of MySKScene but this environment does not provide a container for focus items.
```

So then I tried to just set the SKScene's view, the parent environments focus item container, an empty view and more as the SKScene's focusItemContainer - this fixed the crash, but the focus behaves quite randomly. Some of the nodes cannot be focused then anymore, and the focus just jumps to randoms nodes, and not the one in which direction I swiped to.

```swift
override var focusItemContainer: UIFocusItemContainer? {
    return view // parentFocusEnvironment?.focusItemContainer // UIView()
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I have to set here as the focusItemContainer? It's so strange because everything worked before and I also cannot find anything about any breaking changes in the release notes. If you have any hints for that issue please let me know!

Comment: Same problem here. Overriding focusItemContainer fixed crash. Maybe I have an idea and will come back...

Comment: Good to know that I am not alone with this issue - would be great if you find anything. I will also investigate further on this problem and if I find a solution I will also add it here.

Comment: At the moment: no progress. I tried everything. I have nine buttons on my menu and i can only switch between two buttons. I have no idea why i can't move the focus to the other button. The only thing i know: it worked before tvOS 16. At least i could fix the crash with your tip. I will keep looking...

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I also made a Demo App with a simple grid of focusable nodes and even downloaded the previous Xcode version to double check if it works with tvOS 16 and lower - as soon as I set a focusItemContainer on tvOS 15 it has the same weird behavior as on tvOS 16. I get the feeling that there is maybe an issue on Apple‘s side - I asked the same question on Reddit and the Apple Developer Forums but no answers so far. I also used one of my two yearly code level supports - so let’s see what the Apple employees will answer.

Comment: I have been completely unable to figure out anything :/  It's an amazing example of missing doco!

Comment: Short update: As told from the code level support, I submitted a bug ticket via the Feedback Assistant - as soon as I get an answer I will let you all know.

Comment: New Update: I just had a "Ask Developer Technical Support" call with someone from Apple and got the feedback, that the issue was already noticed from the devs and highlighted as critical issue - but that's still no guarantee, that the bug will be fixed in the next version - maybe it will even be released with a major update during next years WWDC. I mentioned, that I cannot really release without that functionality and got two suggestions: 1. To find another solution for that problem (like use Metal or CoreAnimation? - but that's not really a solution for me tbh)

Comment: 2. that I should again file a feedback with the issue, and to ask for a workaround. I also mentioned, this thread here, that multiple people have this issue and it was recommended, that everyone of you should file in a feedback (the more people raise this issue, the more attention it eventually gets - but unfortunately still no guarantee for that) And lastly he told me to just always update to the latest version to see if it works. So unfortunately it's not a real helpful answer - but if you have the same issue please submit a feedback ticket and lets hope this gets fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: I got an additional answer - I am not totally sure what has to be done here to be honest - does anyone know what exactly needs to be done here? 

"Here’s some follow up from our meeting that I just received from engineering ~ possibly a workaround that you can explore.

If it's possible for the you to calculate the 2D frame of the SKNode relative to the SKView/SCNView then this solution may work - 

1 - developer subclasses SK(Sprite)Node and implements `frame`: manually figure out the CGRect that the Node occupies with respect to the parent view

Comment: 2.1 developer subclasses SKScene and implements: 
   2.2 focusItemContainer - return self
   2.3 focusItemsInRect - return empty array
   2.4 coordinateSpace - return the parent SCNView (or SKView, idk)

You will need to calculate position information and convert that to CGRect that is relative to the parent scene's view."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the issue again with an tvOS 16.4 simulator and it seems like the bug is fixed as everything works as before without any focusItemContainer!